# Padding issue in sidebar

Tags: css, sidebar

I am working on this website. The problem is that I am trying to add `padding-top` to the sidebar but its not working. Please help out. Thanks

```
#sidebar{
    width:300px;
    display:inline;
    padding-top:400px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Padding doesn't work on `inline` elements - change it to `inline-block`

Comment: It's the way `inline` and `block` elements were designed to handle properties, like `height`, `width`, `padding` etc. You can read a bit more here - http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/